# How to install Android APIs and Build-tools from AndroidSDK on a linux server?

Tags: android, linux, terminal, android-sdk-tools

My problem is that I have to install android-sdk in a linux server but I can't access to the linux server only by terminal mode. I downloaded android-sdk, I extracted it and I set ANDROID_HOME on ~/.bashrc file but when I insert this command (to install APIs and build tools):

```
sudo $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android update sdk --filter tools,platform-tools,android-22,build-tools-22.0.1,extra-android-m2repository,extra-google-m2repository,extra-android-support --all --no-ui
```

It throws me an error:

> sudo: /tools/android: command not found

I usually use linux on terminal mode in some times but I don't know how to deal with programs which requires an interfaz or graphics, but now I can only access to the linux server by terminal. Please help me, I'll appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

**edit** the problem in the example is `sudo`, which will clear the environment variables except a few configured exceptions.

---

Apparently your `.bashrc` did not (yet) get sourced in your current terminal.

If you try `echo $ANDROID_HOME` on the terminal you try to run this from, you most likely will get an empty answer.

Try adding your ANDROID_HOME to `$HOME/.profile` as well.

Comment: I set on .profile file too:
 `export ANDROID_HOME=/home/utec/dev/android/android-sdk-linux/
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH`

but `echo $ANDROID_HOME` doesn't work

Comment: Ah, I see now, our are using sudo, which clears the environment. Either configure sudo to keep the variable or better build as non-root. Why are you building as root?

Comment: Well, I just know that I have access to the linux server as root maybe. I just want to install the APIs on my android-sdk because later I'm going to develop an app

Comment: If you are installing inside your own home, there is no need for root at all. You can install it as your normal user. Just skip sudo for that. Make sure that any files you currently have are owned by your user and not root, though.

Comment: Yes I tried it(without sudo), but the terminal throws me: `-bash: /tools/android: No such file or directory` and when I insert `echo $ANDROID_HOME` It just throws me an empty space

Comment: Then you have not set up the environment for your terminal correctly. Sorry, I think I cannot offer more help here, because this now is basic Linux stuff that's very hard to remotely debug. Try to get the echo working. Or try with full path without the variable (actually there is no need for it).

Answer (score 0):

I really thanks to all the people who pay attention and help me on this little problem. I could fixed it and when I put `android` on the terminal it doesn't throws me the error:

```
sudo: /tools/android: command not found
```

To solve this, I just logged out session to the server (just close the terminal). Then, when I entered to the server the `android` command worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post. might be what you're looking for?

http://www.donnfelker.com/setting-up-an-android-build-server-part-3-installing-the-android-sdk/

be sure to read the comments about how to do the install/update of the sdk headless (since you only have terminal access)